# Is there any explicit formula for $x_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Let $a$ be a positive real number and $(x_n)$ be the sequence given by $x_1>0,$ $$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(x_n+\dfrac{a}{x_n}\Big).$$ [It is not difficult to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n)  that $x_n\to\sqrt{a}$ as $n\to\infty.$

My question is : **"Is there any explicit formula for $x_n$ ?"**

Comment: I have seen some math contest problems concerning series like $$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(x_n+\dfrac{1}{x_n}\Big).$$  but have never seen an explicit formula for $x_n$.

Comment: Well this case is way too special LOL

Comment: I had a try for the case where $x_1=2$ and $a=1$, then the first few terms go like this. $x_1=\frac{2}{1},x_2=\frac{5}{4},x_3=\frac{41}{40},x_4=\frac{3281}{3280},x_5=21523361/21523360...$,So it comes to find a formula for the denominator sequence..according to my observation as $n$ goes up it just goes crazily large...so it seems just too hard to me

Comment: @Vim: If you substitute $$y_n=\dfrac{x_n}{\sqrt{a}},$$ then you can transform given recurrence into your recurrence relation. May be you can try to give an alternative proof. Good Luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

since
$$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{x^2_{n}+a}{2x_{n}}$$
so we have
$$x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}=\dfrac{(x_{n}-\sqrt{a})^2}{2x_{n}}\tag{1}$$
$$x_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}=\dfrac{(x_{n}+\sqrt{a})^2}{2x_{n}}\tag{2}$$
$(1)/(2)$ we have
$$\dfrac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}}{x_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}}=\left(\dfrac{x_{n}-\sqrt{a}}{x_n+\sqrt{a}}\right)^2=\cdots=\left(\dfrac{x_{1}-\sqrt{a}}{x_{1}+\sqrt{a}}\right)^{2^{n}}$$
so we have
$$x_{n}=\sqrt{a}\cdot\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{x_{1}-\sqrt{a}}{x_{1}+\sqrt{a}}\right)^{2^{n-1}}}{1-\left(\dfrac{x_{1}-\sqrt{a}}{x_{1}+\sqrt{a}}\right)^{2^{n-1}}}$$

Comment: I corrected a minor typo for you. Please excuse my arrogance! Great answer, +1.

Comment: Gosh!  Incredible!  Before this answer I really believe there is no explicit form.