# limit of Recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $c>0$. Let a sequence $(a_n)$:

$a_1=1$,   $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+\frac{c}{a_{n}})$.

Calculate $$\lim_{n \mapsto\infty }a_n$$

So, my solution is: I can show in induction that $a_n$ is determinated for all $n$.
I showed in induction that $(a_n)$ is trupped between $1$ and $c$, (by seperating the cases of $c>1$ and $c<1$).

I guess I need to separate for the 2 above cases and show that the sequence is monotonous and then I can conclude that the sequence converges, and show that the limit is $\sqrt c$. But I cannot know for sure that there's exist a limit to the sequence.

Comment: Can you show the sequence is monotone?

Comment: No, that's my problem

Comment: [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130082/is-there-any-explicit-formula-for-x-n)

Comment: This a recurrent question (no intended pun) about what is known as the babylonian algorithm: see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Comment: And another version https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n/

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{c}=\frac{(a_n-\sqrt{c})^2}{2a_n}\geq0$$
and
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{c}{2a_n}-\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{(\sqrt{c}-a_n)(\sqrt{c}+a_n)}{2a_n}\leq0.$$
Thus, $a_n\rightarrow\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: one must prove that $$a_n>0$$ for all $n>0$

Comment: Sonnhard,  It's obvious. See the definition of the sequence.

Comment: ok then it is obvious, my name is Sonnhard.

Comment: @ Math Lover I proved that our sequence decreases and $a_{n+1}\geq\sqrt{c}$, which says that there is a limit.

Comment: @Math Lover Yes, of course, for $n\geq2$.

Comment: @Math Lover See please my previous comment.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks. Got it!

Comment: @Math Lover You are welcome!